# Supress action link just for one reader?

Tags: api, facebook-opengraph

Is there a way to suppress the action_link just for one 'reader' of the news?

FB doc (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actionlinks/) says

Suppressing Action Links

If you have configured action links in the App Dashboard you can suppress the action link appearing for a particular story. To do this when you publish the action pass in no_action_link=true.

If user A does something with user B, which generates a story and an action link, when user B sees that in user A's feed, there are scenarios that they shouldn't see the action link. The link could be for something that A did with B which B cannot do with B (like or follow e.g.). User C who is also a friend of A should see that link though since they may want to do that same thing to B. The document above says action_link can be suppressed for a story altogether. Is there a way to mark it so that it doesn't show to B?

Answer (score 0):

It's in the document you linked - if you supply no_action_link on a story, there's no action link for that story

There's no way to have it not display for certain users, if there's user-specific logic taking place, handle it in your code